# Get AWS account ID by name

Tags: amazon-web-services, alias, aws-cli, account

I know there are multiple ways to get AWS account name by its ID, but is the opposite possible? Is there a way to programmatically (`API`, `CLI`, `terraform` etc.) get AWS account ID by its name?

*Update*: Forgot to mention that these accounts exist under organization structure in a specific OU, maybe this could help.

Comment: When you say "AWS account name", what are you referring to?

Comment: @jarmod I guess that would be account alias.

Comment: Based on personal experience, there is no uniqueness requirement for the account name. So any general API would return accounts that you don't control, and therefore would be a security risk. Some accounts, it's true, have a signin URL that includes the account name, but that seems to be chance (or maybe account age): my personal account has a URL that includes the account name, while I have a sandbox account with a name that's almost certainly unique but doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this is not ideal, I realized that `aws organizations list-accounts-for-parent` command is the best compromise. It would give me all accounts within given OU, which I can filter by account name.

Given that my solution will ultimately be implemented in terraform I came out with something like this

```
data "external" "accounts" {
  program = ["aws", "organizations", "list-accounts-for-parent", "--parent-id", local.ou, "--query", "Accounts[?Name==`${local.account_name}`] | [0]"]
}

locals {
   ou           = "ou-12345678"
   account_name = "my-cool-account"
   account_id   = lookup(data.external.tools_accounts.result, "Id", null)
}
```

it would execute AWS CLI command, return back a map of key/values if account info is found, and `lookup` function would retrieve the account ID.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve with the following:

```
data "aws_organizations_organization" "main" {}

locals {
  account-name = "account1"
  account-index = index(data.aws_organizations_organization.main.accounts.*.name, local.account-name)
  account-id = data.aws_organizations_organization.main.accounts[local.account-index].id
}

output "account_id" {
  value = local.account-id
}
```